# How force use of alias of command?

Tags: macros

I am trying to be flexible in my paper by using descriptive macros to allow a possible change of notation in the future.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\energy{\gamma}

\begin{document}
  Suppose that $\energy = 10$ joules...
  Many paragraphs later we recall that $\gamma = 10$ joules.
\end{document}
```

Now my paper is very long and from time to time I forget to use the \energy macro and instead just type \gamma. Is there some way I can have latex warn me or prevent me from using \gamma anywhere in my document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hard way is

```
\newcommand\energy{} % check whether \energy is already defined
\let\energy\gamma
\let\gamma\undefined
```

Then LaTeX will give the error 'undefined control sequence' each time you use `\gamma`.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you could use

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\energy\expandafter{\gamma}
\let\gamma\energy
```

This would work if `\gamma` were expandable, but oddly it is not. The following does work:

```
\def\energy{\mathchar"10D}
\let\gamma\energy
```

It requires knowing the meaning of `\gamma` which I got by writing `\show\gamma`.
I don't know how robust this might be.

Comment: In which way do your definitions prevent a user from using `\gamma` in the document? After them, both commands are identical and produce a gamma; `\gamma` has changed from being a character to being a macro containing this character. What do we gain?

Comment: Change the definition of `\energy` in the answer and then `\gamma` will have the same definition. This doean't prevent one from using `\gamma`, but will prevent `\gamma` from having a different meaning. I guess it does not answer the question as posed, but it does prevent there being two inconsistent symbols for energy, which I took to be the real problem.